# What is the best practice in Craft 3 to sync schema between environments?

Tags: database

How can sync the schema (fields + categories + tags + sections) from development to staging and live? Or should I do it manually?
Is there any support to make migration script instead of do it from the webpage

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the release of Craft 3.1 you can now keep fields (and other things) in sync between multiple environments.

Read more here: https://docs.craftcms.com/v3/project-config.html

Answer (score 3):

See the answer above: project config.

<del>You should check out Andrew Welch's post about it:</del>

<del>https://nystudio107.com/blog/database-asset-syncing-between-environments-in-craft-cms</del>

<del>https://github.com/nystudio107/craft-scripts</del>

ps.: Sorry, Andrew!

Comment: I need to sync the schema. Best pratice is always go from dev to staging to live during golive. So I need the script which sync merge the settings. But thx for the help!

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to sync only configuration you shouldn't use the database sync in the article suggested by Otto - that will also bring over content and users and such - unless you intend to create your fields on production and then pull those into dev (which seems like a strange workflow).

There are two ways to do actual schema syncing in Craft 3 that I'm aware of:

- Writing your own content migrations (using the Craft PHP API to create fields/sections etc by hand)
- Use the architect plugin (currently under development) to sync your config by exporting it to json, then importing it on your other environments. https://github.com/Pennebaker/craft-architect

For Craft 2 there's also Schematic (https://github.com/nerds-and-company/schematic) but there's no word on a release for Craft 3 yet.

Comment: I was trying to find a api doc for that but did but did not get it. We will use that. Could you please link it. I am new in craft yii (coming from laravel) so need to catch up quickly